# Rearrangement of the list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
 m = {{x == 0, y == 0.29264681456942615}, 
      {x == 30, y == 0.2419119568894183}, 
      {x == 50, y == 0.1485164898707659}, 
      {x == 70, y == 0.05437093382683481}, 
      {x == 90 , y == 1.}}
```

I would like to convert it to the form `{{0,0.29264681456942615},{30, 0.2419119568894183}, ... }` (extracting only the numbers form the list).  How can I do this?

Comment: m[[;; , ;; , 2]] should do the trick.
To see why check the result of the following:
Head[a==b], (a==b)[[0]], (a==b)[[1]], (a==b)[[2]]

Comment: alternatively m /. `Equal[_, b_] -> b`

Comment: That's way neater since it can be used even if the order was {3==x,8==y} in some places, m /. Equal[a_, b_] :> If[NumberQ[a], a, b]

Comment: `Map[Last, m, {2}]`.

Comment: @ssch equivalent but perhaps less cryptic for the novice: `m[[All,All,2]]`

Comment: One more for the obfuscation contest: `Last /@ {##} & @@@ m`

Comment: @halirutan auwei!

Answer (score 11):

One of many possible ways is

```
{x, y} /. (m /. Equal -> Rule)
```

What happens here: Let's say you want to transform the expression *x equals 0* into *x is replaced by 0*, then you can do exactly this by `ReplaceAll` (ok, replacing all) `Equal`s in your list into `Rule`s which is done by `(m /. Equal -> Rule)`. The rest is to use it and replace `{x,y}` with these rules.

One disadvantage of this approach which is shared by following solutions from the comments:

```
m[[;; , ;; , 2]]
m[[All,All,2]]
m[[All, All, -1]]
m /. Equal[_, b_] -> b
Map[Last, m, {2}]
```

is that it relies on the fact, that your number is in the end. This can be prevented by using for instance a rule which checks where the numeric value is like suggested by ssch

```
m /. Equal[a_, b_] :> If[NumberQ[a], a, b]
```

Comment: Hmmm... why the `RuleDelayed` in your first example? `Rule` works too. +1 for the didactic explanation.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thx. No special reason. I use `RuleDelayed` more often, since in most of my applications I don't want to rhs to be evaluated. But I see, it is maybe confusing the OP here.

Comment: @halirutan the last rule still needs to be delayed (I couldn't edit because 1 character was considered a low quality edit by the system)

Comment: @ssch Ah, yes, sorry. I was a bit beside me.

Comment: @ssch To explain why I thought it was not necessary: something like `If[boing, a, b]` stays unevaluated as long as `boing` is not `True` or `False`. I thought we can use this here and forgot that `NumberQ[a]` is instantly evaluated to `False`. Sorry again.

Answer (score 2):

```
m = {{x == 0, y == 0.29264681456942615}, {x == 30, 
y == 0.2419119568894183}, {x == 50, 
y == 0.1485164898707659}, {x == 70, 
y == 0.05437093382683481}, {x == 90, y == 1.}};

m /. {x == a_, y == b_} -> {a, b}
```

This returns

```
{{0, 0.292647}, {30, 0.241912}, {50, 0.148516}, {70, 0.0543709}, {90, 1.}}
```

Answer (score 1):

m = {{x == 0, y == 0.29264681456942615}, {x == 30, 
    y == 0.2419119568894183}, {x == 50, 
    y == 0.1485164898707659}, {x == 70, 
    y == 0.05437093382683481}, {x == 90, y == 1.}};

If lists had this shape I would just

```
m[[All, All, 2]]
```

Alternatives are

```
m /. _ == n_ :> n
```

or

```
{x, y} /. (m /. Equal -> Rule)
```

or even

```
Block[{Equal = CompoundExpression}, m]
```

or odd

```
{x, y} /. First /@ Solve /@ m
```

all to get

```
(* {{0, 0.292647}, {30, 0.241912}, {50, 0.148516}, {70, 0.0543709}, {90, 
  1.}} *)
```

Comment: Ok, I just saw that all these except the even and odd ones were already mentioned in comments or answers

Answer (score 0):

```
Block[{Equal = (#2 &)}, m]
```

or

```
m /. Equal -> (#2 &)
```

> {{0, 0.292647}, {30, 0.241912}, {50, 0.148516}, {70, 0.0543709}, {90, 1.}}